# Angular2 set param of current route in routerLink

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

Although it looks trivial, I didn't find any similar cases
Here's my route :

```
{
    path: 'folder/:id',
    component: FolderComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'edit/:form',
            component: 'EditorComponent'
        }
    ]
}
```

When I'm on `edit/form1` page, I can't find the way to specify my routerLink directive so that it just changes the `:form` value, without losing the parent `:id` value.
For now, I need to do that :

**1** `<a [routerLink]="['../../edit, 'form2']">Form2</a>` to get two level up. **This works**. But it's not that elegant...

**2** I tried `['edit', 'form2']`, it brings me to `folder/:id/edit/form1/folder/form2`

**3** If I do `['/edit', 'form2']`, I get `/folder/form2`

**4** I even tried `['', 'form2']`, I get `/form2`

**edit :**

**5** As suggested I tried `['./edit', 'form2']`, but it gives me `folder/:id/edit/form1/edit/form2`

Just to precise, my link is in `editor-component.html` and the current url is `http://myapp.com/folder/:id/edit/form1`

Thx for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using this `./`

```
<a [routerLink]="['./edit, 'form2']">Form2</a>
```

Explanation from [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html)

> The first segment name can be prepended with /, ./, or ../:
>
> 1. If the first segment begins with /, the router will look up the route from the root of the app.
> 2. If the first segment begins with ./, or doesn't begin with a slash, the router will instead look in the children of the current activated route.
> 3. And if the first segment begins with ../, the router will go up one level.

I think number #2 above is what you trying to achive, from what you are describing here :

> When I'm on edit/form1 page, I can't find the way to specify my routerLink directive so that it just changes the :form value, without losing the parent :id value

---

### EDIT

Edit in response to OP comment here :

> Unfortunately, it doesn't work :(. I get `folder/:id/edit/form1/edit/form2`. Maybe I forgot to precise that my navbar is on `editor-component.html` and my current url is `http://myapp.com/folder/:id/edit/form1`

Since the navbar is on `editor-component.html`, now we should use '../' instead, like below

```
 <a [routerLink]="['../form2']">Go To Form 2 From Editor {{id}}</a>
```

Explanation : The link is on the child componenet, so we use `../` to up one level, try to think like this : our current is `http://myapp.com/folder/:id/edit/form1` then `../` will make it up one level to `http://myapp.com/folder/:id/edit/`, so now we just need to append`form2` into it.

Updated Sample code [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TcSPfN?p=preview)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work :(. I get `folder/:id/edit/form1/edit/form2`. Maybe I forgot to precise that my navbar is on `editor-component.html` and my current url is `http://myapp.com/folder/:id/edit/form1`

Comment: Ok, it works :). I didn't take the problem this way, I thought I always had to provide both params : the route and the param.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you are on `edit/form1` page and you have `id` value in `folderId` variable then you can use below `routerLink` to go to `edit/form2` :

```
<a [routerLink]="['folder', folderId ,'edit', 'form2']">Form2</a>
```

Comment: Useful to know it can be done like that. The problem is that I don't have access to `folderId` in the child component (EditorComponent) and I pref not having to pass as input binding :/. Any other solution, or the #1 is the only ? thx

Answer (score 0):

You can also use relativeTo property, like :-
`this.router.navigate(['edit'], {relativeTo:this.route})`

Here `this.route` is an instance of ActivatedRoute

Hope is helps, thanks